# Symfony2 project inside folder hide web/app.php just with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have help-desk project made using Symfony2 and I would like to host the project inside a folder in my website hiding the "web/app.php" from URL. I can't create a virtual host with apache, so I will need to use .htaccess with RewriteRule and RewriteCond. I'm reading and trying for 2 days without success.

I have the folder 'help' in the root directory of website. Inside this folder I have the Symfony with the folders: app, src, vendor and web. 'web' is the public folder that has the app.php controller that handle the resquests. So with the default .htaccess inside the web folder I can access the help-desk system by: www.example.com/help/web that the controller app.php catch the request and redirect to the route 'login' (www.example.com/help/web/login). I would like to access the system just with the URL: www.example.com/help

The original .htaccess inside web folder is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've almost get what I need creating a .htacess inside the help folder with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^/suportefloripa/web/app.php - [L]
   RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /suportefloripa/web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /suportefloripa/web/app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And deleting the .htaccess inside web folder, so when I try www.example.com/help the URL doen't change and I know that the app.php inside web folder was accessed because of a 'echo' that I wrote in the code.

The result is:

```
    String test

    Oops! An Error Occurred
    The server returned a "404 Not Found".

    Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

The 'String test' is a echo that I put inside the app.php (default code from Symfony framework):

```
<?php

echo "String test";

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.
/*
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I think I am almost there But I don't know what I doing wrong.

Comment: Is the route you access available? It seems like the Symfony2 application is throwing this `404` because there is no matching route in any controller

Comment: I've changed now to app_dev.php so it return more details in the error. It is returning the dev page with `No route found for "GET /help/"` so it is wrong because should arrive "/" to match in the routing of my project. Another problem is that the css files are not loading because of this wrong path.

Answer (score 2):

Make a entry in a .htaccess. Suppose you have a website abc.com. You want to run another website in directory. Then create a .htaccess in parent directory pointed to abc.com

Folder Structure

```
   abc.com->index.php
          ->symfony(symfony folder)->app
                                   ->src
                                   ->web
                                   ->vendor


RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !symfony/web/

RewriteRule (.*) /symfony/web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried your code applying to the example above inside the "help" folder without success:
`RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/help$ [NC,OR]   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/help$   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !help/web/   
RewriteRule (.*) /help/web/$1 [L]  `